# compare two spreadsheet and highlight rows don't exist in the first file

Tags: excel, compare, formula

I have two workbooks/spreadsheets - one has 11000 rows and one has 8000.

They both have 10 columns.

I am looking for a way to show what row entries are in the 11000 file that aren't in the 8000 file.

They aren't in the same order, so I can't do a line by line comparison (plus there's 3000 new rows in the second workbook that I need to find)

Thanks!

Comment: If you have a key column in each workbook (or create one by using A1&B1&C1) do a vlookup of one key to another and the items that doesnt have a value is missing in the other

Comment: Have you tried a XLOOKUP,VLOOKUP or INDEX/MATCH to see filter/conditional format the ones that aren't the value you give when not found (will need an iferror in case of the index/match?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the 8,000 row dataset is just a subset of the 11,000.  If one of the 10 columns is a unique identifier, then you can add an 11th column to the 11,000 with a formula such as:

```
=VLOOKUP([@ID],t_8000[ID],1,FALSE)
```

(this is assuming the ID column and then your table of 8000 is called t_8000.  Anything that's #N/A isn't in t_8000.